# Many to Many relationship with "Link table" Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, has-many-through

I have a Modal "ProjectCase" and I'm trying to link the Model "Services" to it.

My database structure is like this:

- ProjectCases

  - id
  - title
- projectcases_to_services

  - projectcase_id
  - service_id
- Services

  - id
  - title

Now I'm trying to make a link between the two and be able to get all the services through the "ProjectCase" model

I've figured out that i should create a function, which uses the **hasManyThrough** function.

I've tried the following:

```
public function services() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Services::class, cases_to_services::class, 'case_id', 'id', 'id', 'service_id');
    }
```

But this returns all the services.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're making it yourself quite hard not to keep the naming conventions Laravel provides out of the box. First of all, try to keep class names single worded in singular form as possible. If `ProjectCases` could also be called `Project`, call it `Project`. `Services` should be called `Service` and the intermediate table should be called `projectcase_service` in singular form. Every other table link to a model should be plural, like `services`, and `projectcases`. Second, an intermediate table should be chronologically ordered, `service_projectcases` would be wrong ;)

Comment: This is linked to an external CMS and thus i cannot modify the table names. ProjectCase should be called Case, but that's reserved for PHP

Comment: Oh boy, well good luck ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Many To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

so in `ProjectCases` model add relationship like below

```
 public function services() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Services::class, 'projectcases_to_services', 'projectcase_id', 'service_id');
    }
```

if you see param option for `belongsToMany` method

```
/**
     * Define a many-to-many relationship.
     *
     * @param  string  $related
     * @param  string|null  $table
     * @param  string|null  $foreignPivotKey
     * @param  string|null  $relatedPivotKey
     * @param  string|null  $parentKey
     * @param  string|null  $relatedKey
     * @param  string|null  $relation
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignPivotKey = null, $relatedPivotKey = null,
                                  $parentKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $relation = null)
    {
    }
```

suggest you to follow laravel naming conventions for models and database table.So that you can keep code clean

Some Naming Convention best practices for laravel

[image]

[image]

Images content used from [Naming Convention Laravel](https://xqsit.github.io/laravel-coding-guidelines/docs/naming-conventions/)

Also you can read here [laravel-best-practices](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices)

Answer (score 1):

For a many-to-many relationship, you need to define a 'belongsToMany' relation on your ProjectCases model:

```
public function services()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Services::class, 'projectcases_to_services', 'projectcase_id', 'service_id');
}
```

You might also want to have a look at the explanations given here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: The intermediate table `projectcases_to_services` should be renamed to `projectcase_service` in order to work out of the box.

Comment: @dbf yes, you have given a very comprehensive description in your comment below the original question on how to name models and tables if you were to follow the laravel naming conventions :)
If you were to do so, it would be sufficient to implement `services()` as `return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class)`.